# Pass custom environmental variables into Kong ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong

So, I need to pass extra env variable to my custom plugin.
In docker compose I just do this:

```
- DATABASE_HOST=mysql:3306
- DATABASE_PASSWORD=mysql
- DATABASE_USER=root
- DATABASE_NAME=kong
- "KONG_NGINX_MAIN_ENV=DATABASE_HOST; env DATABASE_PASSWORD; env DATABASE_USER; env DATABASE_NAME"
```

As you can see it uses Nginx env directive, this is working fine

However I don't know how to do the same with the Kong ingress controller, according to the chart value description:

> Specify Kong configuration
> This chart takes all entries defined under `.env` and transforms them into into `KONG_*`
> environment variables for Kong containers.
> Their names here should match the names used in https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/master/kong.conf.default
> See https://docs.konghq.com/latest/configuration also for additional details

```
  env:
    log_level: info
    my_custom_var: hello
```

So if I put my custom variable there it will be transformed into `KONG_MY_CUSTOM_VAR`

So how can I do it? I cannot find where the Kong chart exposes additional environmental variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the maintainers of the chart, this is not currently possible. I will try to make PR to fix this.